Book about a girl who's trapped in an underground lab and can see the past and future
I read a book a while back but can't seem to remember the name.
It's about a girl who's trapped in an underground lab and can see the past and future.
And one day, a new guy joins the lab and finds her and tries to break her out but failed, so she saves his life by making him forget all about her.
They're both part of a rebel group.

In roughly which year did you read this?

It would be helpful if you would review this checklist - Tips for asking Story Identification questions
